# Is there a way to prevent uploading assets into a parent level folder?

Tags: assets, children, upload, limit

Say that I have a folder structure like this:

```
/images
  /products
  /employee-photos
  /user-photos
  /advertising
```

Is there a way that I could define the single asset source of /images while only allowing uploads to its children?

I would like to do this so that I could simply add new children w/o having to define them as assets sources separately.

Comment: Not currently, the ability to restrict uploads to a folder but still have access to it's child folders is a feature request I made a few months ago: https://plus.google.com/110713469361173113445/posts/HSxvUewJEFH. It might be worth emailing a feature request to support@pixelandtonic.com

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this would be to create a different asset channel for each child directory.